# Can I disable networkd-dispatcher log messages for Docker interfaces?

Tags: docker, syslog, systemd-networkd

I'm using Docker 20.10.14 on Ubuntu 22.04 Server where I'm running a number of containers, and I'm using [Watchtower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower) to automatically update the containers.

Since I updated to Ubuntu 22.04, I've been getting excessive log messages from `networkd-dispatcher` when the containers are updated. This is the log messages I get:

```
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface veth44e6185: initialized
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 428, in _receive_signal
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]:     self.handle_state(iface_name,
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 345, in handle_state
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]:     raise UnknownState(administrative_state)
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]: UnknownState: initialized
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface veth6d82244: initialized
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 428, in _receive_signal
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]:     self.handle_state(iface_name,
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 345, in handle_state
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]:     raise UnknownState(administrative_state)
May  3 01:03:06 xb networkd-dispatcher[1327]: UnknownState: initialized
```

In this particular case, the interface `veth44e6185` is the one that's persisting after the container upgrade, while I assume the interface `veth6d82244` is from the previous container, since this interface no longer exist.

I believe this is because the Docker network interface is reinitialized/restarted for each container when it is updated. The Docker network interfaces are easily recognizable, since the have they format `vethXXXXXXX`, where `X` is a hexadecimal digit.

Everything is working fine after the containers update, but the amount of verbosity in the error messages have gone drastically up with the update from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.

So is there any simple and smart way to disable the `networkd-dispatcher` log messages for the Docker interfaces only?

Comment: I'm also having this in my log many times, and I suspect it's related to IPv6 not working. The DHCPv6 address is not being assigned. Still looking into it.

Comment: I had reported the a bug: [networkd-dispatcher missing state 'initialized'](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/networkd-dispatcher/+bug/1971550). It was a regression from a security update. They released a fix. My IPv6 problem was unrelated, and a little bit PEBKAC.

Comment: I experience similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears upgrading `networkd-dispatcher` to version `2.1-2-ubuntu0.22.04.2` fixes the regression from the previous security update (which was properly [reported as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/networkd-dispatcher/+bug/1971550)).