# Consecutive networkd-dispatcher error messages for virtual Docker interfaces

Tags: docker, syslog, systemd-networkd

My question is much like the issue described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406274/can-i-disable-networkd-dispatcher-log-messages-for-docker-interfaces), except I'm using an LXC of Ubuntu 23.04. In that answer, it was marked as solved because I guess the networkd-dispatcher service was patched. However, I am getting the same errors in 23.04, and the only way I can stop them is by restarting the service. Here is the journal output of the networkd-dispatcher service showing the error in question:

```
Jul 06 19:15:34 docker networkctl[191615]: Interface "veth984df6d" not found.
Jul 06 19:15:34 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Failed to get interface "veth984df6d" status: Command '['/usr/bin/networkctl', 'status', '--no-pager', '--no-legend', '--', 'veth984df6d']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Jul 06 19:15:34 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 397 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:15:34 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 397 seen even after reload
Jul 06 19:16:34 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 399 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 399 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 399 seen even after reload
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 399 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 399 seen even after reload
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 399 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 399 seen even after reload
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkctl[192383]: Interface "veth84307a2" not found.
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker systemd[1]: networkd-dispatcher.service: Got notification message from PID 192383, but reception only permitted for main PID 112
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Failed to get interface "veth84307a2" status: Command '['/usr/bin/networkctl', 'status', '--no-pager', '--no-legend', '--', 'veth84307a2']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 399 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:16:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 399 seen even after reload
Jul 06 19:17:36 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 401 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:17:37 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 401 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:17:37 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 401 seen even after reload
Jul 06 19:17:37 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 401 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:17:37 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 401 seen even after reload
Jul 06 19:17:37 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: WARNING:Unknown index 401 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 06 19:17:37 docker networkd-dispatcher[112]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 401 seen even after reload
```

Is this the same bug reported in v22, but just not updated in 23, or is there some other solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?